# PayPal MECL redirect fail with callback

Tags: callback, paypal, express-checkout

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppmacole/using-callback-api

I am trying to integrate PayPal MECL with instant update referring to the url above.

There is a problem, when I set express checkout with callback.
I got a token after set checkout.
But, the url that I build with the token load sandbox login page like below screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I7Aa.png

I set request below

```
•   ADDROVERRIDE=0
•   ALLOWNOTE=0
•   ALLOWPUSHFUNDING=
•   BANKTXNPENDINGURL=
•   BRANDNAME=
•   BUTTONSOURCE=AngellEYE_PHPClass
•   BUYEREMAILOPTIONENABLE=
•   BUYERID=
•   BUYERREGISTRATIONDATE=
•   BUYERUSERNAME=
•   CALLBACK=http://ip/en/index.php/api/paypal/eccallback
•   CALLBACKTIMEOUT=3
•   CALLBACKVERSION=85.0
•   CANCELURL=http://cancelUrl
•   CHANNELTYPE=Merchant
•   CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER=
•   EMAIL=
•   GIFTMESSAGEENABLE=
•   GIFTRECEIPTENABLE=
•   GIFTWRAPAMOUNT=
•   GIFTWRAPENABLE=
•   GIFTWRAPNAME=
•   GIROPAYCANCELURL=
•   GIROPAYSUCCESSURL=
•   HDRBACKCOLOR=
•   HDRBORDERCOLOR=
•   HDRIMG=
•   LANDINGPAGE=Billing
•   LOCALECODE=US
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=28.00
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Physical
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=METALICPUNCHBLACK
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=lm011
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=3
•   L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=0
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=6.99
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=12.89
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=1
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=0
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=normal
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=express
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=normal
•   L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=express
•   L_SURVEYCHOICE0=Choice1
•   L_SURVEYCHOICE1=Choice2
•   L_SURVEYCHOICE2=Choice3
•   L_SURVEYCHOICE3=etc
•   MAXAMT=140.99
•   METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
•   NOSHIPPING=0
•   NOTETOBUYER=
•   PAGESTYLE=button
•   PAYFLOWCOLOR=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWEDPAYMENTMETHOD=InstantPaymentOnly
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWPUSHFUNDING=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=90.99
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=0
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEOPTIONOFFERED=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=84.00
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERID=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERUSERNAME=YongnamsStore
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=6.99
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=
•   PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=
•   PWD=xxxx
•   REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
•   RETURNURL=http://returnUrl
•   SIGNATURE=AJFQuv....
•   SOLUTIONTYPE=Mark
•   SURVEYENABLE=
•   SURVEYQUESTION=
•   TOKEN=
•   TOTALTYPE=Total
•   USER=z8_135...om
•   VERSION=85.0
```

If I remove callback url, everything is fine.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're logged into your http://developer.paypal.com account in another tab in order to test Express Checkout in the sandbox.  Otherwise, this window you're seeing is what you get.